# When I open App Center I can't view the updates and items I try to download are in a waiting list

Tags: appcenter

[image]

When I open App Center I can't view the updates and items I try to download are in a awaiting list

Comment: Does anything happen when you click the install buttons? Does restarting and then clicking the install buttons help at all?

Comment: I can confirm this as well, with the added frustration that updates are not able to be installed, nor can I view the list of installed programs. Using Gnome-Software until this gets fixed. I wonder if the appcenter-daemon is to blame?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you may be encountering one of these bugs:

- [No error feedback](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1598608)
- [App Center won't update applications](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1598837)
- [Repositories updated after almost every opening AppCenter](https://bugs.launchpad.net/appcenter/+bug/1651596)

Adding details to the bug report and marking yourself as affected can help the developers troubleshoot and prioritize the problem.